# Transform this function completely to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need this function as jQuery.

There is a part jQuery but I am finding a tough time to write the code!

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("drop_em").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $('#scrollbar3').tinyscrollbar();
        }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "list_playlist_popup.php?qq=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can use `$.ajax` in conjunction with the `success` property to run `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: what do you need from this function , do you need to do an ajax request ???

Comment: @jetawe yea , but in jquery ! I am not able to build up a complete function that works using only jquery

Comment: "Only jQuery" is funny … jQuery is just a javascript framework. You can't use jQuery without javascript, so what exactly is "only jQuery"?

Comment: Well, jQuery is an API that is entirely distinct from JavaScript's native API and the DOM API. Is it really that hard to deduce that "only jQuery" means "using jQuery's API"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Because this is the most basic form of AJAX call in jQuery)

```
$.get(
  "list_playlist_popup.php",
  { qq: str },
  function success(data) {
    $('#drop_em').html(data);
    $('#scrollbar3').tinyscrollbar();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
                url:'list_playlist_popup.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                  variable : value
                },
                success:function(data){

                    alert('success');
                }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showUser(str) {
    $.get('list_playlist_popup.php',{qq:str},function(response) {
        $('#drop_em').html(response);
        $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar();
    });
};
```

This is your jQuery equivalent.

Comment: Yes. That's where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste this over the existing function.

```
function showUser( str ) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'list_playlist_popup.php',
        data: {
            'qq': str
        }
    }).done(function( data ) {

        $('#drop_em').html(data);
        $('#scrollbar3').tinyscrollbar();
    });

}
```